# Assign coveredText of a FSArray Annotation to a string Feature

Tags: uima, ruta

Working with FSArray Annotations within UIMA Ruta, I need to extract an annotation's coveredText and store it into a string feature of a different annotation.

As suggested in the [documentation](https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.language.actions.get), I tried using the `GET` action in the following way:

```
ANNOTATION tempAnno;
a:Anno {-> GET(a.items, tempAnno, "dominant"), CREATE(SimpleAnno, "stringFeat"=tempAnno.ct)};
```

but it didn't produce the expected outcome, as the `SimpleAnno.stringFeat` is `null`.

What would be the best way to achieve this?